# Permission error when trying to open folder after restart in Android app

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, kotlin, storage-access-framework

I have a preferences page in my app that asks the user for a place to save a file. This place is returned as a URI using Storage Access Framework and I'm able to use it to store files between activites. The problem is that after I restart the phone, I retrieve the URI from the sharedPreferences, and I receive this:

```
DocumentFile: Failed query: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.externalstorage.ExternalStorageProvider from ProcessRecord (pid=23302, uid=10334) requires that you obtain access using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT or related APIs
```

Here is the code that starts the intent:

```
 folderPicker = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE)        
 folderPicker.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION)
 startActivityForResult(folderPicker, READ_REQUEST_BY_USER)
```

and the onActivityResult:

```
    val takeFlags: Int = folderPicker.flags and (Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION)
    activity!!.contentResolver!!.takePersistableUriPermission(uri, takeFlags)
    val sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(activity?.baseContext)
    with (sharedPref.edit()) {
    putString("savePathURI", uri.toString())
    commit()
    }
```

And this is how I try to reaccess the folder:

```
var uri = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getString("savePathURI","")                
var getSelectedDocument = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(applicationContext, Uri.parse(uri))!!
var params = BridgeParams(applicationContext, links, filesDir.absolutePath, button, getResources(), progressBar3, getSelectedDocument, contentResolver)
```

EDIT: I noticed that calling contentResolver.persistedUriPermissions always returns an empty array even if I call it right after:

```
activity!!.contentResolver!!.takePersistableUriPermission(uri, takeFlags)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem was that I needed to add additional flags for the [ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#grant-access-directory):

```
folderPicker = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE)        
folderPicker.addFlags(
Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION
or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION
or Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PREFIX_URI_PERMISSION
)
startActivityForResult(folderPicker, READ_REQUEST_BY_USER)
```

Comment: quite interesting how my app was working fine for a long time without needing to do this.

Comment: I have problem it's work in `startActivityForResult` but not when I use `registerForActivityResult` can u tell me y?

Answer (score 5):

You need to call `takePersistableUriPermission` on `onActivityResult`

see : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html?authuser=1#takePersistableUriPermission(android.net.Uri,%2520int)

Comment: I already have that in my code. I wonder though... it looks like it never gets applied. Calling contentResolver.persistedUriPermissions returns an empty array even if I call it right after the takePersistableUriPermission

Comment: what are the flags ??

Comment: which flags? All code is available on the question.